# useFirestore always return undefined value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, vueuse

I am using `useFirestore` to get a user using uid and always returns undefined value.

```
const user = useFirestore(doc(db, 'users', uid));
console.log('user', user);
```

[image]

Comment: How do you get the value of `uid`? Do you take into account the fact that the Auth object can be in an intermediate state—such as initialization— and therefore `uid` could be null. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: I have uid from the current auth user and it is not a null value.